# Join two array with adjacent elements

Tags: arrays, join

I have two integer arrays with different sizes.
I also have a third integer array.
I want to take each element from the first two arrays and store them one by one in the new array.

This is my code

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] c = new int[100];
int i = 0, j = 0, k, m;
for (k = 0; k < a.Length + b.Length; k=k+2)
{
    while (i < a.Length)
    {
        c[k] = a[i];
        i = i + 1;
        break;
    }
    while (j < b.Length)
    {
        c[k + 1] = b[j];
        j = j + 1;
        break;
    }
}
for (m = 0; m <= a.Length + b.Length; m++)
{
    Console.Write(c[m] + " ");
}
```

Now this code does not produce the desired output. The 2nd to last element becomes a 0, because at that point the 1st array is over.

my desired output is `{ 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 8 }`
whereas I get `{ 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 0, 8 }`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need nested loops, this algorithm is probably more optimal:
decide which is the shorter, loop on it, and copy the shorter and longer arrays' values. Then go through the rest of the longer one.

if a and b matters which one comes first then use their minimum length instead of array.

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
int[] shorter = a.length < b.length ? a : b;
int[] longer = a.length < b.length ? b : a;
for (int i = 0; i < shorter.length; i++) {
  c[2*i] = shorter[i];
  c[2*i+1] = longer[i];
}
for (int i = shorter.length; i < longer.length; i++) {
  c[shorter.length+i] = longer[i];
}

 for (int m = 0; m < c.length; m++)
 {
     System.out.println(c[m] + " ");
 }
```

Comment: Thank You, the program is working and giving the desired output, but there is a slight problem, if the size of a[] is bigger than b[], then the c[] is taking the element of the b[] array 1st.
i.e. if a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } and b[] = { 5, 6, 7 }, the output is showing c[] = { 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4, 5} whereas i want {1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 5}

Comment: @halflife272 yes, yes that's why I told you to use index instead of renaming the arrays. Ok.